# Creating C program calculating a percentage is giving me an issue

Tags: c

I am creating a poll that asks some questions and the displays the results. One is calculating the percent of female students that work AND are married. I keep getting the percent result as 0.00 and I am unsure why. Below is my code for said part of the project

```
char pollAnswer[0];
char Gender[0];
int i = 0;
float female = 0;
int enteredAge;
float age = 0;
char work[0];
char married[0];
float workMarried=0;
float percentFemale;
int numChildren;
float childrenAge;
int socialMedia;
int twitter = 0;
int facebook = 0;
int google = 0;
int linkedln = 0;




do {
    printf("1) Gender? (F/M)\n");
    scanf("%s", &Gender[i]);

    if (Gender[i] == 'F') {
        female++;
    }

    printf("2) How old are you?\n");
    scanf("%d", &enteredAge);

    if (enteredAge <= 25) {
        age ++;
    }

    printf("3) Do you work? (Y/N)\n");
    scanf("%s", &work[i]);

    printf("4) Are you married? (Y/N)\n");
    scanf("%s", &married[i]);

    if (work[i] == 'Y' && married[i] == 'Y') {
        workMarried++;
    }


    //Need help with children part.
    //printf("5) how many children do you have?");
    //scanf("%d", &numChildren);

    printf("6) What is the social media you use the most?\n 1. Twitter\n 2. Facebook\n 3. Google+\n 4. Linkedln\n Social Media (1-4): ");
    scanf("%d", &socialMedia);

    if (enteredAge <= 25) {
        if (socialMedia == 1){
            twitter++;
        }
        else if (socialMedia == 2){
            facebook++;
        }
        else if (socialMedia == 3){
            google++;
        }
        else linkedln++;
    }


    printf("Do you want to answer the poll? (Y/N)\n");
    scanf("%s", &pollAnswer[i]);
} while (pollAnswer[i] == 'Y');


percentFemale = (workMarried / female);

printf("What percent of female students work and are married? %f\n", percentFemale);

//Code for average age of the children.

printf("What is the favorite social media of the students with an age less than or equal to 25 years?\n");

if (twitter > facebook && twitter > google && twitter > linkedln) {
    printf("Twitter\n");
}

else if (facebook > twitter && facebook > google && facebook > linkedln) {
    printf("Facebook\n");
}

else if (google > twitter && google > facebook && google > linkedln) {
    printf("Google+\n");
}

else if (linkedln > twitter && linkedln > google && linkedln > facebook) {
    printf("Linkedln\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you tried debugging?  like printing workMarried and female values?  or loading it into a debugger?

Answer (score 2):

You arrays declarations are wrong, you are creating `0` size array, for example:

```
char pollAnswer[0];
```

Create enough large array to store values as `char pollAnswer[SIZE];` then index can be from `0` to `SIZE - 1`.

Second `scanf` statement is wrong as you want to `scanf` only single char:

```
scanf("%s", &Gender[i]);
```

correct it as:

```
scanf("%c", &Gender[i]);
```

You are getting 0.00 because following code never gets chance to execute as you are not storing char but address by using wrong format string:

```
  if (work[i] == 'Y' && married[i] == 'Y') {
        workMarried++;
    }
```

`workMarried` remain `0` and answer is 0.00.

Comment: +1.  Hope you don't mind me editing to correct a couple of typos

Comment: @simonc Thanks to correct my typos. Actually it helps me, I always check were I make English mistakes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

charge these declarations

```
char pollAnswer[0]; 
char Gender[0];
char work[0];
char married[0];
```

You need character only

```
char pollAnswer;
char Gender;
char work;
char married;
```

if you get issue of escaping `scanf()`

Use space before format specifier.
for example

```
scanf(" %c", &work);
```

Comment: You are suggesting him don't use arrays, but I have impression from all of his code that OP wants to use arrays.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Please see code again, you will found why OP used those variables you can simply figured it whether OP need characters or arrays and why OP tried to declared arrays. op NO where compared array with strings and No where increased index.

Comment: That I believe because he don't correct know to use arrays. Btw I am not sure and as I said I have impression that he wanted to use arrays. And of-course your suggestion is also correct too because technically he don't need to use arrays.

Comment: Yes OP don't know how to use arrays correctly He might fix now.Based on OP code one can easily get impression As you have.Yes, technically he don't need to use arrays.